# jobname or alias for background job

Tags: background-process, jobs

Is there any way to put names or aliases for identification in jobs?

I tried a clumsy

```bsh
> sleep 10 & # this job sleeps 10 seconds
```

but `jobs` returns

```bsh
[1]  + running    sleep 10
```

And I couldn't find any command to do this, such as

```bsh
> sleep 10
(hit ctrl-z)
> setnametobackgroundprocess %1 -name "this sleeps 10 seconds"
```

Thank you

---

**EDIT**
Using '%' for accessing process name is not helpful in my case because I am launching many processes all with the same command, and since '%' automatically expands with the launched command I cannot distinguis which is which. Hence why I am trying to give them a unique identifier; I am exploring the idea of getting something like:

```bsh
>jobs
[1]  - running  myapp # launched by ID 28
[2]   running  myapp # launched by request of external
...
```

Comment: I'm sorry if I misunderstood you, but you can refer to jobs by the prefix or part of their command line. For `sleep 10 &` you can use either `fg %sl` or `fg %?'p 1'`

Comment: you are right, my question is misleading. My question originates because I need to launch some processes with the same command, but different config file. Therefore using `fg %<name>` doesn't help, because I have tens of processes having the same <name>. Let me edit the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could misuse variables for this:

```
bash-5.0$ foo=bar sleep 10 &
[1] 22335
bash-5.0$ jobs
[1]+  Running                 foo=bar sleep 10 &
bash-5.0$ fg %foo=bar
foo=bar sleep 10
```

So maybe something like:

```
n="ID 28" running myapp &
n="external" running myapp &
```

where `n` is a variable that your app is not likely to be using.

Comment: so simple and I couldnt think about it! simple is best. Thank you!!

Comment: Good idea on this. I wish I could write a plugin that sits between `ctl-z` and bg that asks you to name the buffer.

Comment: @pixelearth you could maybe use Ctrl-x-e and use Vim or emacs for editing, and have the editor automatically add the `&` on save and quit.

Comment: @muru not sure I follow